# Is it possible to conclude $ G $ is supersoluble if $ H $ is of odd order ?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ G $ is a finite group. Suppose $ H \unlhd G $ such that $ G/H $ is supersoluble. Suppose $ H \cap M $ is either $ H $ or a maximal subgroup of $ H $ for any maximal subgroup of $ G $. Suppose that $ P_{H}(M) = \langle h \in H \mid \langle h \rangle M = M \langle h \rangle \rangle = H $ for any maximal subgroup $ M $ of $ G $. Let $ p \in \pi(G) $ be an odd prime, then $ G $ is $ p $-supersoluble. Is it possible to conclude $ G $ is supersoluble if $ H $ is of odd order ?

Comment: Why would you ask that?

Comment: @tomasz Because i read in the article but i don't understand how conclude

Comment: In that case, you should provide a link. You should always provide some context of your questions (even if the context is "I've been thinking about this and that and something like $x=y$ came out"), especially with such a specific question.